# Getting a raw xml code from a single DOM element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm currently trying to get a part of an xml using DOM with Java language.
For instance I would like to be able to have as a String the raw code of an XML Element (Tag) and it's children nodes.

Example :

XML file :

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

The goal is to have this for the 1st book element :

```
    <book category="cooking">
     <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
     <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
     <year>2005</year>
     <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
```

I'm looking in the  Element methods, I can't find some method useful for this in it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3C DOM does not have a convenient "toXML" like some of the alternative Java XML APIs provide, you need to use either the `javax.xml.transform` API or an `org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer`.  Assuming a variable `doc` containing the DOM `Document`, you can obtain an instance of `LSSerializer` like this:

```
// import org.w3c.dom.ls.*;

DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation();
LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
```

Once you have one of these, then you can serialize any `Node` from that document as an XML string using

```
String xml = ser.writeToString(node);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into xpath. While generally xpath is used in the context of HTML it stands for the XML Path Language, try the following.

> //book[contains(@category,'cooking')]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Java. I edited the main post.
Can the Xpath retrun me a String with raw XML ?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217397/java-xpath-extract-subdocument-from-xml